# How would you implement a fixed-point operator (Y combinator) in F#?

Tags: f#, lambda-calculus, y-combinator, fixpoint-combinators

I'm using F# to create a lambda calculus. I am currently stuck trying to figure out how I would implement the fixed-point operator (also called Y combinator).

I think everything else is in order. Expressions are represented by the following discriminated union:

```
type Expr =
 | Const of int
 | Plus  of Expr * Expr
 | Times of Expr * Expr
 | Minus of Expr * Expr
 | Div   of Expr * Expr
 | Neg   of Expr
 | Var   of string
 | Fun   of string * Expr
 | App   of Expr * Expr
 | If    of Expr * Expr * Expr
```

My `eval` function seems to work. The following examples all yield the expected results.
example 1:
`> eval (Fun("x",Plus(Const 7,Var("x"))));;`
`val it : Expr = Fun ("x",Plus (Const 7,Var "x"))`
example 2:
`> eval (App(Fun("x",Plus(Const 7,Var("x"))),Const 3));;`
`val it : Expr = Const 10`
example 3:
`> eval (If(Const 0,Const 3,Const 4));;`
`val it : Expr = Const 4`

But as I mentioned, I'm having difficulty implementing the fixed-point operator within my lambda calculus. It  is defined [here](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeFP/Lambda/Ch/01.Calc.html) as:
`Y = lambda G. (lambda g. G(g g)) (lambda g. G(g g))`

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've looked at other questions regarding the Y combinator, but couldn't find anything that I was able to successfully adopt.

All help is appreciated.

**Edit:** Fixed a typo in the code... previously I had `Mult` instead of `Minus` in the discriminated union. Funny that I just noticed that!

Comment: You might be interested in these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998407/how-do-i-define-y-combinator-without-let-rec http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003225/rosetta-stone-y-combinator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version that you're referring to works only with a lazy language, and if your language isn't using a lazy evaluation strategy, you'll get stuck in an infinite loop.  Try translating this:

```
Y = lambda G. (lambda g. G(lambda x. g g x)) (lambda g. G(lambda x. g g x))
```

Comment: I actually am trying to use normal order evaluation, so as you mentioned the version I referenced should work. I'm just having problems translating it I suppose.

Comment: If your interpreter should be lazy, and the plain version diverges, then you have a bug and a test case...

Comment: I think you are missing me... I can't figure out how to translate from the notation used `lambda G. (lambda g. G....)(.....)` to one useable in my F# implementation. It is confusing to me how I am supposed to reference G and g within each other and apply them to each other.  I hope that makes my problem a little clearer.

Comment: Um, are you saying that you don't know how to *translate* that expression into your F# constructors??  That would be easy (and probably a good that you should write a parser): `Fun("G", App(Fun("g",App(Var("G"),App(Var("g"),Var("g")))), Fun("g",App(Var("G"),App(Var("g"),Var("g"))))))`.

Comment: Thanks Eli, that was exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall it, there are a whole class of Y Combinators in untyped lambda calculus, but it gets difficult to implement even one if your language is strictly typed, although people have tried to do special cases in ML and also F#. It doesn't seem to be very useful if your language supports recursion (which lambda calculus does not). Have a look at the discussions on that topic that Stackoverflow has seen flagged with generic "functional programming" or ML, I think there are some insights to be had:

[Y-Combinator Practical Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869497/y-combinator-practical-example)

Comment: (1) It's not *that* difficult -- [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440304/code-that-exercises-type-inference), (2) it's not as useful in a language that has recursion, but there are still uses for it ( [a cute example](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/ruby/ycombinator.shtml) in addition to your SO link), (3) lambda calculus certainly has recursion (*using* the Y combinator, of course).

Comment: @Eli Ad (3), well yes... you need the Y Combinator because otherwise there's no recursion, so once you use it, then there's recursion. Pretty much what I was saying in my clumsy way.

Comment: @Eli - that's true of the untyped lambda calculus, but the simply typed lambda calculus doesn't support recursion (nor can the Y-combinator be expressed).

Comment: kvb: Right, but both the original question and Alexander's answer were showing *untyped* calculus, so why would I talk about something else....